# $(3y^2-x) \Bbb dx+2y(y^2-3) \Bbb dy=0$ admits an integrating factor which is a function of $x+y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is: show that the differential equation $(3y^2-x) \Bbb dx + 2y(y^2-3) \Bbb dy = 0$ admits an integrating factor which is a function of $x+y^2$. Hence solve the equation.

I took $f(x+y^2)$ as an integrating factor, and calculated $\frac {\partial M} {\partial y}, \frac {\partial N} {\partial x}$ from the new equation, but still $\frac {\partial M} {\partial y} \ne \frac {\partial N} {\partial x}$.
Please help me out.

Comment: Please show your computations in detail.

Comment: I got ∂M/∂y= 2y(3y²-x)f′(x+y²) + 6yf(x+y²)
∂N/∂x= -6yf(x+y²) + 2y(y²-3x)f′(x+y²) , clearly ∂M/∂y≠∂N/∂x. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: "Clearly"? How so? Remember you can *choose* the function $f$.

Comment: yes, but I am unable to find that function f(x+y²).

Comment: One can transform the identity ∂M/∂y=∂N/∂x one gets when using the expressions of ∂M/∂y and ∂N/∂x in your comment, into a rather simple differential equation that f must satisfy. Did you try this?

Comment: I tried. The function which I am getting is  f(x+y²)=1/(x+y²)³. But, this still does not make the equation exact.

Comment: Again: explain how you got this f instead of saying "I got this, I am stuck", after which no one can help you.

Comment: I proceeded as follows: Since, ∂M/∂y= 2y(3y²-x)f′(x+y²) + 6yf(x+y²); ∂N/∂x= -6yf(x+y²) + 2y(y²-3x)f′(x+y²)
Putting ∂M/∂y=∂N/∂x
The simplified form of the equation is:
-3/(x+y²) = f′(x+y²)/f(x+y²) 
On integrating both sides of the equation with respect to (x+y²).
f(x+y²) = 1/(x+y²)³ .  Am I right or I have made mistake somewhere?

Comment: So you **did** find some integrating factor f(x+y²), right?

Comment: Yes, but this value of f is still not making the equation exact. I guess, I am making mistake somewhere...

Comment: If  ∂M/∂y=∂N/∂x the equation is exact, this is a theorem...

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Actually, there was a typo. Thanks for guiding me through the question.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, there is a typo or a mistake in the wording of the problem.

There is no integrating factor on the form $f(x+y^2)$ for the equation :
$(3y^2-x) \Bbb dx + 2y(y^2-3) \Bbb dy = 0$ as it is proved below.

Of course, the ODE can be solved with other method (rather complicated).

[image]

After correcting the typo in the wording of the question :

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a typo. The correct equation is: (3y²-x)dx+2y(y²-3x)dy=0. Sorry. I cross checked it from a different source. Anyways, thanks for the above solution.