# Integrating factor $(3y^2-x) + 2y(y^2-3)y'=0$ is a function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that the differential equation $(3y^2-x) + 2y(y^2-3)y' = 0$ admits an integrating factor which is a function of $(x+y^2)$. Hence solve the equation.

I know how to solve this by using Integrating Factor of an exact equation

But question specifically asking solving using a function. How to approach this question.

Comment: Hint: write this of the form $M \ dx + Q \ dy = 0$ and use the info here: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html

Comment: You are missing the point when you say "solving using a function." The point is that the equation admits an integrating factor (which is *always* a function), but *in this particular case*, the integrating factor depends *only* on the value of $x+y^2$, not on the values of $x$ and $y$ individually. So it is a function of $x+y^2$, not really a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503317/3y2-x-bbb-dx2yy2-3-bbb-dy-0-admits-an-integrating-factor-which-is-a-f

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503317/3y2-x-bbb-dx2yy2-3-bbb-dy-0-admits-an-integrating-factor-which-is-a-f

Answer (score 0):

$(3y^2-x)+2y(y^2-3)y'=0$

$2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x-3y^2}{y^2-3}$

$\dfrac{d(y^2)}{dx}=\dfrac{x-3y^2}{y^2-3}$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{x-3u}{u-3}$ $(\text{Let}~u=y^2)$

Let $\begin{cases}x=t+a\\u=v+b\end{cases}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{t+a-3v-3b}{v+b-3}$

Take $a=9$ and $b=3$ , the ODE becomes

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{t-3v}{v}$

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{t}{v}-3$

Let $w=\dfrac{v}{t}$ ,

Then $v=tw$

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=t\dfrac{dw}{dt}+w$

$\therefore t\dfrac{dw}{dt}+w=\dfrac{1}{w}-3$

$t\dfrac{dw}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{w}-3-w$

$t\dfrac{dw}{dt}=-\dfrac{w^2+3w-1}{w}$

$\dfrac{w}{w^2+3w-1}~dw=-\dfrac{dt}{t}$

$\int\dfrac{w}{w^2+3w-1}~dw=-\int\dfrac{dt}{t}$

$\dfrac{(13+3\sqrt{13})\ln(2w+3+\sqrt{13})}{26}+\dfrac{(13-3\sqrt{13})\ln(2w+3-\sqrt{13})}{26}=-\ln t+c$

$(2w+3+\sqrt{13})^{13+3\sqrt{13}}(2w+3-\sqrt{13})^{13-3\sqrt{13}}t^{26}=C$

$\left(\dfrac{2v}{t}+3+\sqrt{13}\right)^{13+3\sqrt{13}}\left(\dfrac{2v}{t}+3-\sqrt{13}\right)^{13-3\sqrt{13}}t^{26}=C$

$(2v+(3+\sqrt{13})t)^{13+3\sqrt{13}}(2v+(3-\sqrt{13})t)^{13-3\sqrt{13}}=C$

$(2(u-3)+(3+\sqrt{13})(x-9))^{13+3\sqrt{13}}(2(u-3)+(3-\sqrt{13})(x-9))^{13-3\sqrt{13}}=C$

$(2(y^2-3)+(3+\sqrt{13})(x-9))^{13+3\sqrt{13}}(2(y^2-3)+(3-\sqrt{13})(x-9))^{13-3\sqrt{13}}=C$

Which is impossible to solve by considering the integrating factor of the function type $x+y^2$

Answer (score 0):

No integration factor in form $ \mu(x,y) = \mu(x^2+y)$ exists.

We must to change equation  to the form

$$ (3y^2 -x)dx +2y(y^2 -3x)dy =0.$$

See: [$(3y^2-x) \Bbb dx+2y(y^2-3) \Bbb dy=0$ admits an integrating factor which is a function of $x+y^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503317/3y2-x-bbb-dx2yy2-3-bbb-dy-0-admits-an-integrating-factor-which-is-a-f)